# I am getting the below error for the following code to detect a particular color

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, color-detection

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 


# Load our input image
image = cv2.imread('./images/domino.png')
cv2.imshow('Original',image)

# We use cvtColor, to convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Getting the original image dimension
height,width= gray.shape[:2]

#Creating a threshold image with same size as that of original image
threshold = np.zeros((height,width,3), np.uint8)

#BGR Threshold value 
Min=np.array([255,255,255],dtype = "uint8")
Max=np.array([255,255,255],dtype = "uint8")

#Creating the output image on the basis of RGB thresholds   
threshold = cv2.inRange(gray,Min,Max)

#Displaying the output image
cv2.imshow('Threshold', threshold)

#Saving the output image 
cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', threshold)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hi I am trying to mask out a particular value of BGR in an image but i am getting the below error for the code above .

> error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
>        in ()
>            25 #Creating the output image on the basis of RGB thresholds
>            26 
>       ---> 27 threshold = cv2.inRange(gray,Min,Max)
>            28 
>            29
>
> error: ........\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:2703: error: (-209) The lower bounary is neither an array of the same size and same type as src, nor a scalar in function cv::inRange

Comment: error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ec6e1f1a6fcb> in <module>()
     25 #Creating the output image on the basis of RGB thresholds
     26 
---> 27 threshold = cv2.inRange(gray,Min,Max)
     28 
     29 

error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:2703: error: (-209) The lower bounary is neither an array of the same size and same type as src, nor a scalar in function cv::inRange

Comment: You are trying to mask a grayscale image using three channeled boundaries. Replace `gray` with `image` in `threshold = cv2.inRange(gray,Min,Max)`

Comment: Thanx @JeruLuke. It works